# meaning of "the profession of reality"

Tags: meaning

[A post](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-house-price-predictor-using-ml-through-tensorflow-in-python-cbd2b637904b) says

> The **profession of reality** is moving into the 21st century, and as you can imagine home listings are flooding the internet. If you have ever looked at buying a home, renting an apartment, or just wanted to see what the most expensive home in town is (we have all been there), then chances are you have been to Zillow, Realtor.com, Readfin, or Homesnap.

I understand the [meaning of profession](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/profession)

> any type of work that needs special training or a particular skill, often one that is respected because it involves a high level of education

I also understand the [meaning of reality](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reality)

> the state of things as they are, rather than as they are imagined to be

I don't understand the meaning of "profession of reality". I [googled it](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&sxsrf=ALeKk01hBg58Y5igT-bI92g64TAcVpX59g%3A1587119554823&ei=woWZXvLlMeGHr7wP0d6Z0AI&q=meaning%20of%20%22profession%20of%20reality%22&oq=meaning%20of%20%22profession%20of%20reality%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDFAAWABggq8BaABwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjyzp-Koe_oAhXhw4sBHVFvBioQ4dUDCAw), got only 3 hits, but none gives any explanation.

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the context it seems to be a spelling mistake.
Reality should be [realty](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/realty).

> property in the form of land or buildings

If that is the case, the profession of realty means property/real estate related professions.